# Rafael pie chart labels: how to add text

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using the basic pie chart example on http://raphaeljs.com/pie.html, I'm trying to add the values to the labels. So instead of reading "Ruby", it will now read "Ruby 40%".

By changing a line in the js, i can easily add the values:

```
labels.push($("th", this).text());
```

Changes to:

```
labels.push($("th, td", this).text());
```

The problem is, this returns the label and the value together one after the other, so I get: "Ruby40%".

How do I add a space or a dash between the two?

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest answer, but I think you need to add a bit more logic to your code to make it do that:

```
var label ="";
$("th, td").each(function(){
    label += $(this).text() + " ";
 }
);
labels.push(label);
```

Hope this helps!